# Trouble understanding physics behind MOSFET body effect

Tags: electric-circuits, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

I’m struggling to understand why a negative voltage applied to the bulk contact of an n-type MOSFET increases the threshold voltage. I can see why it happens due to the equations, but I can’t wrap my head around how it actually works.

I have 2 questions:

1. Applying a negative voltage to the bulk makes the potential difference (and thus the field?) between the gate and the bulk greater, which should make it easier to attract electrons under the gate. Why is this wrong?
2. Intuitively, the negative voltage at the bulk terminal repels electrons, pushing them towards the gate. Doesn’t this mean that the electron concentration under the gate increases more rapidly, reducing the threshold voltage?

**Edit after John's answer:**

Thank you, I think I get it now, but what would happen if we instead considered a MOS capacitor, so with no n+ doped regions? There I can't see how the threshold would increase.

**Edit, answer to the MOSCAP edit:** in the case of a MOS capacitor, since we have no n+ doped regions, I think the negative bulk potential helps the gate accumulate electrons, reducing the threshold Voltage.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic before my question was edited I mentioned that I asked in the EE site as well, but the question remained unanswered

Comment: Crossposted from https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/621390/52589

Comment: @Qmechanic thanks for adding that, didn't know I needed to mention it

Comment: What's the "threshold" of a MOS capacitor?

Comment: @JohnDoty in my course the threshold voltage of a moscap was defined as the gate voltage at which strong inversion is achieved in the channel, so basically when the channel is formed I guess? Even though it's not really a 'channel' since it's not connecting anything, it's more like an accumulation of electrons at the surface of the semiconductor

Comment: @ale_zec To get an inversion in P Si, you need electrons from somewhere, so you need a source/drain structure in the vicinity.

Comment: @JohnDoty I believe you’re wrong on that one, electrons are accumulated via the generation process, its just slower I think, take a look if you like [here](https://www.chu.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Chenming-Hu_ch5-1.pdf)

Comment: @ale_zec Possibly very slow. Typically nA/cm^2 at room temperature, very temperature dependent. If you want an actual capacitor, put a gate over a heavily doped region so that it just acts as a conductive plate. If you want a weird nonlinear "capacitor" with a threshold, well, my friend Professor Ikeda of ISAS and KEK does that, but he draws such things as MOSFETs with source and drain shorted to be clear about what the object really is.

Comment: @JohnDoty yeah it’s not a great capacitor, we used it just as a gateway device to analyse before MOSFETs, to better understand their behaviour. It’s a very slow process, with gate signals of more than a few Hz it ends up modulating the depletion layer width instead of creating an inversion layer. Thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electrons are "squeezed" into the space bounded by the gate and the body. In the common enhancement-mode MOSFET, the body has a built-in negative potential which blocks electrons in the source from entering the channel. Positive potential on the gate can counteract this, allowing electrons to flow. But negative potential on the body can, in turn, increase the potential barrier, blocking the flow.

Comment: Thank you. So applying a negative body potential is like reverse biasing the source-body pnj. The 2 effects I mentioned aren't exactly wrong then, maybe just not relevant since the channel is 'built' using electrons from the source, right?

Comment: Yep. Note that you can make a depletion mode MOSFET by (lightly) doping the channel to make it N-type. Then, electrons are "naturally" present in the channel, and current flows at zero gate bias. If you connect the MOS gate to source, and use the body as the gate, you have a JFET.

Comment: Thank you John, I get it now, super helpful. Could you address the edit about the MOS capacitor if you're able?